# Swift | macOS | Retrieving track title and artist of currently playing music

Tags: swift, macos

I've embarked on a mini project to try and learn to write Swift. I thought it would be useful to write a **MacOS** app that would display currently playing track title and artist info in the menu bar. At the moment I have to open the app in question, whether that be Spotify, Apple's Music or Tidal, which disrupts workflow.

Given that the new-ish "Now Playing" notification widget displays this already (regardless of the source of audio), I figured it would be fairly simple to do something similar for the menu bar.

**I have researched thoroughly** and read related yet **very dated** questions, which suggest the only now playing info/data available is from iTunes, however it looks like things have evolved since then, especially since iTunes is to be killed off, so I'm re-asking and hoping things are more global in 2020.

With regard to code I've discovered [nowPlayingInfo](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter/1615903-nowplayinginfo) which suggests it might do what I'm after but I've spent 4 hours trying to get it to work without success. I've also looked at [MPNowPlayingCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpnowplayinginfocenter) but, similarly, had no result.

There seems to be lots of help regarding **setting** *Now Playing* info, but very little regarding retrieving/**get**ting it.

So far I've managed to write the code to add text to the menu bar:

```swift
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system
        statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(
            withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        statusBarItem.button?.title = "This should be a string of the track name and artist"

    }
```

I've also gathered snippets of potentially useful code:

```swift
        // var nowPlayingInfo: [String : Any](? {})
        // let MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: String
        // let MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: String

        // static let MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange: NSNotification.Name
        // MPNowPlayingPlaybackState

        // class var applicationMusicPlayer: MPMusicPlayerController { get }

        // class MPNowPlayingInfoCenter : NSObject
        // let nowPlaying = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo
        // let trackName = nowPlaying.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as String
```

After half-a-day of trial-and-error, with Xcode warning me of errors, and lots of research I'm turning to the experts on stack overflow for some guidance.

Comment: I don’t think what you’re asking for is possible. Other apps can _tell_ the now playing info center what they are playing, so there is a central way for the system to display that info. But you have no way to _ask_ the now playing info what it knows.

Comment: Ah, disappointing, but thank you for the response @matt

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer the question completely since I'm not a Swift developer. However, I can offer some insights since I'm thinking about a similar project to learn Swift.

1. There is [`systemMusicPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624179-systemmusicplayer) in MusicKit's `MPMusicPlayerController`. The documentation says that it "returns the system music player, which controls the Music app’s state". It has a [`nowPlayingItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/1624245-nowplayingitem) property which may be what you need.
2. There is a 3rd-party app called [Emcee](https://ilyabirman.net/projects/emcee/) that displays the currently-playing track info. The website mentions iTunes but I can confirm that it works with Music app in Catalina, so retrieving currently-playing track is certainly possible. It even displays the star rating of the song, see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3uo7.png). (I'm new to SO so can't embed images in answers yet, sorry.) During installation, this app asked my permission to access Music app, so I guess it uses official Apple Music APIs.

Hope this helps somewhat, and good luck with your project! Please post back if you'll be successful in your task.

Comment: This is really useful Oleg, I appreciate the time you took to respond. Once I get some time I'll investigate further and respond here!

Comment: Did you ever end up figuring this out?